# Using Java Predicate and Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, predicate, functional-interface

Why does the below code return `Predicate<String>` and not `boolean`?

My understanding is that the `!s.isEmpty()` check here is going against the Predicate `boolean test(T t);` The return type here is `boolean`.

So in my lambda should my `nonEmptyStringPredicate` not be of type `boolean`? Obviously, it's not, I'm just trying to understand why it's not.

```
Predicate<String> nonEmptyStringPredicate = (String s) -> !s.isEmpty();
```

Comment: It seems you are confusing what lambdas *does/returns*, with what type of functional interface it *implements* (as instance of what type it can be used).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `Predicate` gets in this case a `String` as parameter and returns a `boolean`.
In case we don't write it as lambda it would look like this:

```
Predicate<String> somePredicate = new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String string) {
        return !string.isEmpty();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! - So if I am to use a Predicate it will always return with Predicate<T> of what I pass in, in this case String.

Comment: You're welcome. If you need more information about lambdas check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/functional-interface-and-lambda-expression). Btw, you shouldn't forget to accept an answer to show others the problem is solved.

Answer (score 6):

If you really are willing to get a boolean though from the `Predicate`, you can use its [`test`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test(T)) method:

```
Predicate<String> nonEmptyStringPredicate = s -> !s.isEmpty();
boolean val = nonEmptyStringPredicate.test("any"); // true
```

[`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) on the other hand is just a [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), that you've represented using a lambda expression.

Answer (score 4):

Lambda is like an anonymous class, so this:

```
Predicate<String> nonEmptyStringPredicate = (String s) -> !s.isEmpty();
```

Is like:

```
Predicate<String> nonEmptyStringPredicate = new Predicate<String>() {
    public boolean test(String s) {
        return !s.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lambdas and AIC are *similar* but not the same. They have some slight differences (i.e. what `this` means) and they are implemented in a total different way.

Comment: You are right, but I do think It is a good way to visualize lambdas or explain to one how should he use them.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the below code return Predicate and not boolean?

This is because the type of the **function** `(String s) -> !s.isEmpty()` is a `Predicate<String>`, at this point you're simply defining **a function** (which says "given a String as input return a boolean value indication whether it's empty or not).

Note that at this point you're not evaluating anything hence the result is not a boolean but rather a **function**.

Definition of FI from the doc:

> Functional interfaces provide target types for lambda expressions and
>   method references. Each functional interface has a single abstract
>   method, called the functional method for that functional interface, to
>   which the lambda expression's parameter and return types are matched
>   or adapted. Functional interfaces can provide a target type in
>   multiple contexts, such as assignment context, method invocation, or
>   cast context:

in order to get the "boolean result" you're seeking, you must first invoke the "functional method". example:

```
Predicate<String> nonEmptyStringPredicate = s -> !s.isEmpty();
boolean result = nonEmptyStringPredicate.test("");
```

Answer (score 0):

A predicate always returns a boolean so the only interesting value here is the input parameter which is a String.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html

Answer (score 0):

It returns a predicate because on the left hand side you declared predicate as return type, and on the right side you are returning the implementation of Predicate's `test()` method.
When your code returns an object which is the inplementation of a functional interface (like in your case) you simply return the logic of its single abstract method, in this case `test()`
So basically is as ifyou are returning this:
`Predicate<String> nonEmptyStringPredicate = new Predicate { @Override boolean test(String input) { return input.isEmpty() } }` 
When you write the code as you wrote it, the compiler 'knows' that `!s.isEmpty()` is the logic of method `test`, it basically tells you "hey give me just the logic, i dont need the boilerplate code"
Btw is good practice to use method reference, you can replace `!s.isEmpty()` with `!String::isEmpty`