# How to sort with 2 Objects from 2 Classes by 1 properties

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

Assume I have two classes:

class 1:

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    public Person(){}
    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    @Override
    String toString(){
        return "Name: "+name + "\tAge: "+age;
    }
}
```

class 2

```
class Animal{
    String name;
    int age;
    public Animal(){}
    public Animal(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    @Override
    String toString(){
        return "Name: "+name + "\tAge: "+age;
    }
}
```

And I create a List Object to stored 2 classes Person and Animal

```
List newList = new ArrayList<>();
newList.add( new Person("person", 20);
newList.add( new Person("aPerson",20);
newList.add( new Animal("animal",20);
newList.add( new Animal("aAnimal",20);
```

Now i want sort `newList` by `name` but i don't know how to do it.
With one Class I can Create Class `SortByName` and compare name between two Object, But with two Class i can not

Comment: You would need to create an abstraction. Example: `Entity` interface which contains a` getName () ` method that gets implemented by both entities. So you can use that type in the `compare` method.

Comment: Base class say NamedObject they both depend on would be one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an `Interface`. Both your `Animal` and `Person` class offer `name` as one of their properties, so you can have an `Interface` say `Nameable` in this regard to essentially specify that your class definitely has `name` property.

You'll code to the Nameable interface so as to create a list of Nameable's and you can create a sorter on that list.

```
List<Nameable> list = new ArrayList<>();
newList.add( new Person("person", 20);
newList.add( new Person("aPerson",20);
newList.add( new Animal("animal",20);
newList.add( new Animal("aAnimal",20);

list.sort(new Comparator<Nameable>() {
    public int compare(Nameable o1, Nameable o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
});
```

The interface ans its usage:

```
Nameable.java

public interface Nameable {
    String getName();
}

public class Person implements Nameable {
   ...

   String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   ...
}

public class Animal implements Nameable {
   ...

   String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An abstraction for that specific case is needed that holds all the information which both entities need. E. g. an interface called `Entity` which has the method `getName()`.

Example:

```java
public interface Entity {
    String getName();
}
```

```java
public class Person implements Entity {

...
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Animal implements Entity {

...
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

After you got this you can use it by type:

```java
List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
entities.add(new Person("person", 20);
entities.add(new Person("aPerson", 20);
entities.add(new Animal("animal", 20);
entities.add(new Animal("aAnimal", 20);
entities.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
```

It would also be possible to use an `abstract` class.

Comment: entities.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());

Comment: It is a lambda expression that does the same as the example from @Pdb. In this case, it overwrites the `compare` method of the `Comparator`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53633161/8052043) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56183593/8052043).

Comment: yep, I did try it, and I know it is short ways to Overwrites compare, but the first time I see it, Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

After creating a Base class/interface as suggested in other answers, you can sort as with `Comparator.comparing`,

```
newList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Entity::getName));
```